# 1 pixel causes bootstrap columns to overflow, also how can I make my column size dynamic?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-centered">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Header',
                                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
                      'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu ) ); ?>
        </nav>
</div>


/* css*/

.navbar-nav {
display:table;
width:100%;
margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
display:table-cell;
text-align:center;
border-right: black 1px solid;
}

.col-centered
{
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

I have a navbar which has a custom amount of navigation buttons. I tried adding a border-right: black 1px solid to help show separation between the buttons, but this causes the column to overflow.

I also have a problem where if I make the columns 1 bigger than the amount of buttons, there will be extra blank space at the end, and if it is 1 smaller than the amount of buttons then it will break the straight line also.

How can I make it so the 1 pixel border does not cause the overflow, and also how can I make the columns dynamic to fit the amount of navigation buttons?

Comment: Remove border from last child.https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Comment: @nevermind i added a border-right:none to my last li child, still overflows

Comment: @albert For your menu items, try using `box-sizing: border box` so that borders are included into width calculations (presently they're counted as additional width, which may be causing the items to break to the next line).

Comment: @Serlite still overflows...

Comment: @albert Your CSS either isn't selecting the elements correctly, or your priority isn't high enough for the rule. The `.navbar-nav` element isn't acting like a table if the children can flow to the next line like in your picture. Using a more specific selector or using `!important` would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the table container you are using is too small and is forcing the navigation to wrap if any more width is added. Your table class is `col-xs-3` which is using 3 'blocks' out of the total 12 that are available.

Change that line to use `<div class="col-xs-12 col-centered">` and it should fit to use the whole width. Hope that helps.

**Edit**
Based on your comment below [here is a JS.Fiddle with the code](https://jsfiddle.net/L8r2vgfb/) I am talking about.

Comment: I don't want it to be col-xs-12 though because I don't want my nav bar to take up the full width. I want it like the same size as the amount of buttons

Comment: @albert the col-xs-12 is just a container that is holding your navigation. If that container is too small then your navigation will wrap. If you dont want your navigation not to fill the entire width of the <div class="col-xs-12 "> then just remove the 100% from your UL nav-bar class.